# Another System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements (using .Any())

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, elmah

Getting the exception on this line:

```
public bool isEngageOn()
    {
line 149  -> return chatUserRepository.Table.Where(c => c.TrackingOn).Any();
    }
```

`TrackingOn` is of type boolean.

**.Any()** is suppose to "Determine weather a sequence contains any elements", so why the exception "System.InvalidOperationException Sequence contains no elements" caught on Elmah?

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
 at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
 at sf2015.Models.DomainModels.Services.ChatServices.isEngageOn() in C:\....\ChatServices.cs:line 149
```

p.s.: Can't reproduce the error but it shows up on [Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) error logs sometimes.

Below is some of the code for the repository

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Entities;
        }
    }

    private DbSet<T> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_entities == null)
                _entities = Context.Set<T>();
            return _entities;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post a couple of preceding lines?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson check updated question and let me know if enough.

Comment: Which query provider are you using?  It would seem that the query provider messed something up.

Comment: Strange that `Single()` is in the stack trace.  Do you get the exception in the web site or just in Elmah?  Could Elmah be configured to report handled exceptions as well?  Perhaps the provider implements `Any()` by seeing if `Single()` throws an exception?

Comment: @Servy I'm using System.Linq and System.Data.Entity (sorry, not sure that answer you query provider question).

Comment: @JoaoLeme: Which database system are you using? SQL Server? SQL Server CE? MySQL? etc. With SQL Server most likely it will be the SqlClient provider... For another DB it can be another provider.

Comment: @Slauma its SQL Server so SqlClient provider

Comment: I've added the `elmah` tag. If you can't reproduce the error and it only shows in elmah log maybe someone with good knowledge of elmah has an idea.

Comment: Is that all the code from all instances of `isEngageOn()`?

Comment: @Jodrell Yes. Thats all for isEngageOn().

Comment: Can you log the SQL that gets sent to the database during `isEngageOn`? Search for EFTracingProvider, turn on the logging during `isEngageOn`, turn it off afterwards, and if an exception is raised during `isEngageOn`, include the executed query in the exception log?

Comment: I have a similar problem and it's driving me crazy.  When it happens, I have to restart the web server to fix it.

Comment: it's not on any but on single

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper use would be

`return chatUserRepository.Table.Any(c => c.TrackingOn)`

Comment: The original query will do the same database query and work exactly the same, writing the same query using another syntax is not an answer to his question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Jordan. Will save me some typing next time.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace you've provided says that the exception is from `.Single` which does throw the mentioned exception if no elements are found. You can change the mentioned code to:

```
 return chatUserRepository.Table.Any(c => c.TrackingOn);
```

Which will do the same as your line.

Comment: So you are saying that @Joachim Isaksoon comment above is wrong (its not the same). I've changed the code that way a while ago and haven't seen the error message on Elmah (besides the fact that haven't spent much time going over Elmah errors lately), so I guess that may have fixed it. Thanks. I will set as correct answear for Jordan and if I findout otherwise later we go from there.

Comment: @joaoleme It might do the same (and probably will) but whether it does is an implementation detail and depends on the type of the collection. However that's beside the point. The condenced version reads more like English and therefor helps to understand the intention. Which of course is personal preference on my behalf

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

Was using the method `Any()` but the StackTrace shows error on the `Single()` method.

The cause of the problem was the method Seed() on the Entity Framework Code First `Configuration` class.

My `Seed()` method was using the `Single()` method on a table that has no registries.